# class object serializable for ViewState storage not working in c# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, object, viewstate, serializable

I’ve created a panel to store my ListBoxes, my goal is to add new Listboxes dynamically when I press the Button control on the page.

I’ve created a MyList class that inherits List class and I’ve applied the [Serializable] tag. I've applied serialized to store the object in the viewstate.

The MyList class will store all the ListBoxes dynamically created.

**questions:**

- When the code runs, the page loads but when I click the button to
  store the viewstate of the list I get an error, how come?
- As far I know I just had to serialize the MyList class to store it in
  the viewstate, is this correct?
- Do I also need to serialize the base class (List) of MyList?

  ```
  public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
      MyList<ListBox> myList;

      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          myList = new MyList<ListBox>();
          myList.Add(new ListBox());
          Panel1.Controls.Add(myList[0]);
          Button1.Click += Add_ListBox1;
      }

      public void Add_ListBox1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          ListBox temp_listBox = new ListBox();
          myList.Add(temp_listBox);
          Panel1.Controls.Add(temp_listBox);
          ViewState["ListBox_list"] = myList; 
      }
  }

  [Serializable]
  public class MyList<ListBox> : List<ListBox> 
  { 

  }
  ```

***page laoded before clicking:***

[image]

***error message after clicking button:***
[image]

Comment: The System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox is not a serializable component. I think that any Listbox you add to the webpage will automatically use the viewstate. For what purpose do you wnat to store mylist?

Comment: The listboxes will be used to create a product category selection. Depending on the selection made on one listbox the sub categories will show on the next listbox. It has to be dynamic, because the number of listboxes can vary depending on the subcategories or categories selected. Listboxes need to be transfered to the server to read and write data from the db.

Comment: I agree with Brian on this. Perhaps you could use a treeview instead of using dynamic listboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you've marked your class [serializable], it depends on ListBox which is not serializable.

I did a little googling and found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/328547) which may help, although it looks more involved than I would expect.

Couple quick thoughts:

- Dynamic content is one of the weaker spots in WebForms because, as you're seeing, the dynamic content is lost after postback, so it must be persisted and re-created in some way. In these situations, I try to and eliminate postbacks and rely more on JavaScript so the browser never gets reset... And this is one of the places where the new MVC model shines, because it isn't constantly fighting you (as the postpack model inadvertently does). Actually, this pain is one of the main things nudging us towards single page applications.
- You might be better off writing your own class that contains what you care about regarding these listboxes, such as position and their contents which is hopefully just some simple strings, and serialize that instead... Then write your own code to de-serialize them into ListBoxes.

Nothing against webforms by the way, I have one open right now in another window!

Comment: off topic, but still: Many aspects of the site I’m creating are based on dynamic contents, such as this listbox enquiry. The website I’m trying to build is an ecommerce from scratch. I’ve already built all my database logic. Reading what you’re saying about using webforms dynamically discourages me in proceeding, I’ve invested so much time in learning ASP.net webforms, but what if I restart all with MVC, will there be a dramatic learning path? Is MVC the trend?

Comment: @Luther When I say dynamic content, what I mean is specifically adding new controls on the fly . Is that what you're up to?

Comment: Yes, adding forms, controls... programmatically

Comment: @Luther Well I wouldn't say it's just the wrong direction, webforms *is* perfectly capable of handling this... It's not super easy no matter what platform you use. The thing is you lose some of the power of postbacks, because if you use postbacks it will require you to re-build everything. So you end up writing all this state-rebuilding code. But maybe that's not the end of the world.

Comment: @JohnSaunders  Thanks for letting me know why you downvoted me John. However, I kindly ask you to read it again, as I don't think I said what you think. :) I stated that the postback model of webforms fights you in the specific situation of working with dynamically created content because using it causes the content to be lost. If there's some way that's not true I would sincerely like to know how to get there, as this has been a pain point on several projects.